# MVP and dynamic tabs

Tags: gwt, tabs, mvp, tabpanel

Does anyone try to create panel with dynamic added tabs.
My requirements:

- First tab is not closeable and has a list of items.
- From this first view you are able to edit item which is done by context menu and creating new tab.
- you can add new item by creating new tab.

As I can say there are few views on the screen. EditItemView, ListItemView...
My question:

- How to create this architecture in MVP style?

Answer (score 0):

dynamic tab Items in WPF

```
<TabControl  Grid.Row="4" Name="TabControla" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfProcess}"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="330"  
    VerticalAlignment="Top">

    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                                 
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProcessDesc}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid Name="dtlgrid" Height="330" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProcessDesc}" Margin="4,6,3,28"/>
                    <my:DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FOIDtl}" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  
                        Margin="4,6,3,28">

                        <my:DataGrid.Columns>
                            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Characteristics" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=Character}" 
                                IsReadOnly="True" Width="140">
                            </my:DataGridTextColumn>
                            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Method Of Checking" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=MethodOfCheck}" 
                                IsReadOnly="True" Width="140">
                            </my:DataGridTextColumn>
                            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="(1)" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=AfterReel1}" 
                                IsReadOnly="False" Width="70">
                            </my:DataGridTextColumn>
                            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="(2)" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=AfterReel2}" 
                                IsReadOnly="False" Width="70">
                            </my:DataGridTextColumn>
                            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="(3)" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=AfterReel3}" 
                                IsReadOnly="False" Width="70">
                            </my:DataGridTextColumn>
                            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="(4)" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=AfterReel4}" 
                                IsReadOnly="False" Width="70">
                            </my:DataGridTextColumn>
                            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="(5)" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=AfterReel5}" 
                                IsReadOnly="False" Width="70">
                            </my:DataGridTextColumn>
                            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Remarks" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=Remarks}" 
                                IsReadOnly="False" Width="70">
                            </my:DataGridTextColumn>
                        </my:DataGrid.Columns>
                    </my:DataGrid>
                </Grid>                                    
            </StackPanel>                                            
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```